# C++ Shorten wchar_t array

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to shorten wchar_t array. Example:

```
wchar_t* email = L"name@domain.com";
/ * Somehow leave in email just "name" * /
```

My idea to do that

```
wchar_t Domain = L"@domain.com";
if(!(pos = wcsstr(email, Domain)))
    return 0;

wcsncpy (pos,L"",1);
```

wcsstr returns address to "@domain.com"(0x000001 - email begins, 0x000005 @domain.com begins ) but there wont be any memory leaks or garbage?

Comment: You can say `email[4] = L'\0';` and continue using `email`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that won't create any memory leaks because you aren't allocating any memory, or modifying your original `email` pointer.

An easier and more efficient syntax, though, would be `*pos = '\0';`

Comment: Thanks for drawing attention :)